# Using inline SVG in the wysiwyg/backend cms elements

Tags: cms, wysiwyg, svg

How can i get the wysiwyg/backend cms editor to accept inline svg code,
i want to make the svgs stylable which means they need to be injected.

Yes i can inject them via javascript, but this causes more server requests and other issues.
So i would like to give the admin the ability to add svg code via the cms backend, but by default i assume that the wysiwyg purges any unknown tags and any inline svg gets removed on save.

Comment: So i am digging through the docs: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/components/wysiwyg/configure-tinymce-editor.html but as usual they are not very complete or explicit